# Slack event for when a bot authorization is removed

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack app that works across workspaces. I'm using the `app_uninstalled` event to update my database when a workspace uninstalls the app, but I can't figure out how to handle when a user removes the bot authorization from the app Settings page.

When this happens, the app is effectively uninstalled, but I need my app to get notified when this happens. I've tried the `tokens_revoked` event, but it's not being sent.

**The short course:** I'd like my app to get notified when the trash can icon (in the image down there) is clicked. Thank you!

[image: The user-facing Settings page for a Slack app]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've worked with the slack events APIs, `tokens_revoked` is the method which is triggered when a user clicks the trash-bin you are talking about and confirms the action. I've just confirmed it a few minutes ago as I'm also facing a similar (not same) issue.